# Creating a code editor for javascript with Qt 4.8 (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, editor

I want to create an intelligent code editor for javascript (like notepad++) using C++ in Qt 4.8

What are your suggestions?

Comment: An "intelligent **cod** editor" might come in handy some times, but I don't see the relation with coding... ;) I'll edit the question to fix the spelling. for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Lazy answer to a lazy question:

QtCreator has a JavaScript editor with syntax highlighting and all the fancy stuff. QtCreator is written in Qt. Use QtCreator if you only want to use an editor or look into the source code if you want to create your own.